# Keep angular controller thin

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

At this moment i working on huge angular SPA application. I try to keep my controllers thin:

```
<div ng-controller='HomeController as home'>
   <div ng-repeat='var item in home.items' ng-bind='item' ></div>
   <button ng-click='home.remove(1)' >remove</button>
</div>

function HomeController (homeService){
    var vm = this; //$scope
    vm.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    vm.remove = remove;

    function remove (id){
        homeService.remove({ items: vm.items, targetId: id });
    }

    //a lot of other logic here
}


angular.module('my').service('homeService', homeService);
function homeService (){
    this.remove = remove;

    function remove (param){
        for(var a = 0; a < param.items.length; a++){
            if(param.items[a] == param.targetId){
                param.items.splice(a, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Advantages:

- Logic is outside of controller

Disadvantages:

- Service change scope state

What is your approach to keep controllers thin?

Comment: What is the meaning of "Service change scope state"?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, i edit my code, I just want to say, in service a change var items and this changes will affects ui.

Comment: A service should not know about ui!

Comment: Yeah, this is the main problem. May i ask, how do you organized code in your controllers or any advice how can i improve the code above?

Comment: I suggest posting code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for in-depth advises

Answer (score 4):

> What is your approach to keep controllers thin?

I personally like to keep anything related to application models inside factories/services. So `remove` and `item` in your code would not be defined in the controller. Inside the controller I would set references to the model for whatever needs to be available to directives i.e. accessible via `$scope`.

As an example, consider a model with an array of entities and methods to add/remove/find entities in the array. I would first create a factory exposing my model and methods to work with it:

```js
angular.module('myApp').factory('model', function() {

    // private helpers
    var add = function(array, element) {...}
    var remove = function(array, element) {...}
    var find = function(array, id) {...}

    return {
        Entity: function(id) {
            this.id = id;
        },
        entities: {
            entities: [],
            find: function(id) {
                return find(this.entities, id);
            },
            add: function(entity) {
                add(this.entities, entity);
            },
            remove: function(entity) {
                remove(this.entities, entity);
            }       
        }
});
```

Then pass the model to my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ctrl', function($scope, model) {
    $scope["model"] = model; // set reference to the model if i have to
    var entity = new model.Entity('foo'); // create a new Entity
    model.entities.add(entity); // add entity to entities
    model.entities.find('foo'); // find entity with id 'foo'
});
```

etc.

Comment: You may want to rename `.Entity` into `.getEntityById` or `.getById` to make it more readable. Also naming `.Entity` breaks the standard camelCase convention, for which I don't see any reason.

Comment: The `model.Entity` function is not meant to be a retrieval/getter function, but a class to be instantiated in the controller, as in `new model.Entity('id')`. Hence the capitalisation I used.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I miss in your example are directives. Directives are a powerfull Angular tool that allows you to reuse code, encapsulate and expose the behaviour in your html. To keep the controllers thin you need to split your logic in directives and services. I would write your example with something like: (not working code, I wrote something to ilustrate the idea of splitting the logic)

```
// "home"
<div ng-controller='HomeController as home'>
   <my-item ng-repeat='var item in home.items' ng-bind='item'></my-item>
</div>

// itemtemplate.html
<div>
    {{ item.name }}
    <button ng-click='remove()' >remove</button>
</div>

function HomeController (homeService){
    var vm = this; //$scope
    vm.items = homeService.items;

    // The idea here is to make this controller 
    // only needed to load content for this route, 
    // all the other logic should be in the directives and services 
}

angular.module('my').directive('myItem', funcion(homeService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'itemtemplate.html',
        controller: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.remove = function(){
                homeService.remove(scope.item);
            }
        } 
    }  
})

angular.module('my').factory('homeService', homeService);
function homeService (){

    var items = [];

    return { 
        loadItems: function() {
            items = [... pick the items from server or whatever ...];
        },

        remove: function() {
            for(var a = 0; a < this.items.length; a++){
                if(this.items[a] == this.targetId){
                    this.items.splice(a, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I also moved the items array to the service (I also changed it for a factory as I think services get instantiated with every injection and you need to keep the items available to everyone), this way it can be accessed from other controllers or directives and the controller doesn't have to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using not only thin controllers but also change controller state from the controller itself.

```
function Ctrl($scope, Service) {
     var ctrl = this;
     $scope.ctrl = ctrl;
     Service.getData().then(function() {
          ctrl.data = Service.data;
     })
}

function Service ($http) {
    var data = [];
    this.getData = function() {
         return $http.get().then(function(res) {
              data = res;
         });
    }  
}
```

This construction causes application data flow to be directed one way. So I'm always sure when data will be refreshed and always can track where data is coming from.

Of course I make some exclusions. E.g. if you have no need in data persistence (data should be removed on $destroy) I will save state in the controller.

Also I like splitting Service to view Service and data Service, where view service is responsible for the view state like detailed/list view, classes etc.

Also I like using own event bus to avoid using watch expressions and broadcast/emit

More iver the most useful thing is to move all flags like $scope.viewType, $scope.pageClass etc. to separate directives. This will lead to extreme readability of the code

Answer (score -2):

Why you are using `var vm = this;`? Did you know `this` will point to instance controller? Where `$scope` has two way data binding. Also to remove element from array, it can be done with one or two line. Removing it in controller seems legit, imo.

Please check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13841/

Comment: Hi, about "vm = this" you can read here https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y031 . 'Also to remove element from array, it can be done with one or two line.' - I deliberately used simple example, instead remove logic you can imagine any other complex logic.

Comment: @mola10 what do you mean by _Disadvantage: Service change scope state_?